# Update Cart automatically Using Increment and decrement Button in cart page Magento 2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento2

I have included + and - to increment and decrement the quantity of a product in the cart page. Now i need to update it automatically without clicking the update shopping cart button. How can i do that? Kindly help me to fix this problem

Comment: simple, add the update cart function to the + and - buttons

Comment: Hi @CollinterSteege. Basically i'm new to magento. So i need to know the entire steps to do that. Kindly provide the steps to do that

Comment: your answer is already here @DaneshG explained it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery ajax() Method
[ajax function tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="button-minus"> - </button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 0;
   $("#button-minus").click(function(){
     if ( count > 0 ){
        $.ajax({url: "url here", success: function(result){
            $("#div").html(result);
            count--;
        }});
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Danesh G. Can you explain how to include this content in magento?

Comment: you can use above function as it is in your templates (*.phtml) files. I request you to go through complete tutorial here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-overview.html

Comment: Thanks @Danesh for your reply